# Java function inside __groovy executes but the result is not being assigned to a variable

Tags: java, http, groovy, jmeter

I'm new to jmeter. I'm executing a java function which encrypts data and I'm trying to assign the output of the function in my Http request body. The function executes and I can see the response in the jmeter console but the value for some reason is not being assigned. Here's what I've tried so far :-

```
  "key":  "${__groovy(new com.util.EncUtil().encrypt(),)}"
```

The encrypt function in the EncUtil class encrypts the required data and returns the result. I want to assign this returned value in my Dynamic Http request. What should I change?

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) you'll see that __groovy() function has 2 parameters:

1. Groovy script to run
2. Name of variable to store the result

[image]

So you can amend your function to look like:

```
${__groovy(new com.util.EncUtil().encrypt(),encryptedValue)}
```

---

Alternative option is using `vars` shorthand

```
${__groovy(vars.put('encryptedValue'\, new com.util.EncUtil().encrypt() as String),)}
```

`vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in the thread context, check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article to learn more about this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and __groovy() function.

---

In both cases you will be able to refer the generated value as `${encryptedValue}` later on where required.